# Running Shell Script in parallel for each line in a file

Tags: shell

I have a delimited (|) input file (TableInfo.txt) that has data as shown below

```
dbName1|Table1
dbName1|Table2
dbName2|Table3
dbName2|Table4
...
```

I have a shell script (LoadTables.sh) that parses each line and calls a executable passing args from the line like dbName, TableName. This process reads data from a SQL Server and loads it into HDFS.

```
while IFS= read -r line;do
    fields=($(printf "%s" "$line"|cut -d'|' --output-delimiter=' ' -f1-))
    query=$(< ../sqoop/"${fields[1]}".sql)
    sh ../ProcessName "${fields[0]}" "${fields[1]}" "$query"
done < ../TableInfo.txt
```

Right now my process is running in sequential for each line in the file and its time consuming based on the number of entries in the file.

Is there any way I can execute the process in parallel? I have heard about using xargs/GNU parallel/ampersand and wait options. I am not familiar on how to construct and use it. Any help is appreciated.

Note:I don't have GNU parallel installed on the Linux machine. So xargs is the only option as I have heard some cons on using ampersand and wait option.

Comment: Are you **very** sure your `ProcessName` is in fact a POSIX sh script, not a bash script? In general, `sh foo` is a worse practice than just `./foo`, which lets `foo` itself choose its interpreter via the shebang line (`#!/bin/sh`, `#!/bin/bash`, etc).

Comment: ...your existing code depends on arrays, which are a ksh feature adopted by bash, and so won't work on any shell that implements only the baseline POSIX sh spec [a set of shells which includes `dash`, which is the default `/bin/sh` implementation on Debian and derivatives including Ubuntu] -- which is why I'm less than confident that the other code you're calling is likely to be written to that spec. [...completeness addendum: There's actually a small set of extensions that dash does incorporate; for instance, it supports the `local` keyword, which isn't POSIX-specified].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an `&` on the end of any line you want to move to the background. Replacing the silly (buggy) array-splitting method used in your code with `read`'s own field-splitting, this looks something like:

```
while IFS='|' read -r db table; do
    ../ProcessName "$db" "$table" "$(<"../sqoop/${table}.sql")" &
done < ../TableInfo.txt
```

---

...FYI, re: what I meant about "buggy" --

```
fields=( $(foo) )
```

...performs not only string-splitting but also globbing on the output of `foo`; thus, a `*` in the output is replaced with a list of filenames in the current directory; a name such as `foo[bar]` can be replaced with files named `foob`, `fooa` or `foor`; the `globfail` shell option can cause such an expansion to result in a failure, the `nullglob` shell option can cause it to result in an empty result; etc.

---

If you have GNU xargs, consider the following:

```
# assuming you have "nproc" to get the number of CPUs; otherwise, hardcode
xargs -P "$(nproc)" -d $'\n' -n 1 bash -c '
  db=${1%|*}; table=${1##*|}
  query=$(<"../sqoop/${table}.sql")
  exec ../ProcessName "$db" "$table" "$query"
  ' _ < ../TableInfo.txt
```

Comment: ProcessName is actually LoadTables.sqoop which is a single file. So I want to execute this same file for every line in TableInfo.txt in parallel.

Comment: @snate, ...so change `../ProcessName` to `../LoadTables.sqoop`, or such as needed. "Execut[ing] this same file for every line in parallel" is, well, what this answer exists to accomplish; I'm unclear on the concern.

Comment: Concern is with & option, I'm getting "There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue. Cannot create worker GC thread. Out of system resources." error message. Is there a way I can restrict number of processes to use. I have CPU:total 32 (8 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core).

Comment: Yes, there are some ways you can do that, though the most obvious ones use `xargs` or `parallel`, and the obvious ways to do it in bash that scale cleanly [and don't do something ugly like have a separate `awk` instance filtering for each CPU in use] use modern features, so I'd want to (1) be targeting bash, not POSIX sh, and (2) know the specific version of the shell.

Comment: is there any good examples for my case on how to use xargs... i can't use gnu parallel as its not installed and am not allowed to install too...

Comment: First, which implementation of `xargs`? A POSIX-standard xargs isn't good enough, you need to have the `-P` extension available (which is a GNUism).

Comment: Amended a solution depending on GNU xargs.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax. If I have a file which has multiple fields per line delimited by | how would I parse it. For an example, in TableInfo.txt its like First row has dbname1|tblname1|field1|field2|field3. How would I do parse and get each field.

Comment: @snate, ...that's what the `IFS='|' read -r db table` content in my answer does. If you want on array, make it `IFS='|' read -r -a fields`, or just something like `IFS='|' read -r db tbl f1 f2 f3` if you know how many fields there are.

Comment: @snate, ...to use `read` with content passed on the argument list, just put `<<<"$1"` on the end.

Comment: Did you mean this --> xargs -P "$(nproc)" -d $'\n' -n 1 bash -c '
  IFS='|' read -r db tbl f1 fe f3;
  query=$(<"../sqoop/${tbl}.sql")
  exec ../ProcessName "$db" "$tbl" ''f1'' ''f2" "f3" "$query"
  ' _ < ../TableInfo.txt <<<"$1"

Comment: @snate, err, no. The `<<<"$1"` is for the `read` command only. "On the end" meant "on the end of the `read` command" in that context.

Comment: Sorry my bad... I pasted it in the wrong location... got it working... appreciate your time and effort on helping me...